# scatterplot in 3d

Tags: scatterplot, ellipse

[image]I have several points in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. When I create a 3D scatterplot of the points, they seem to lie on an ellipsoid as shown in the above plot. How do I interpret the plot ? Does it indicate that the points follow a trivariate normal distribution ?

Comment: On or inside? Can you post the plot?

Comment: See the plot in the edited question.

Comment: We can't judge a complex distribution from this plot. It's not obviously inconsistent with it, as far as I can see. And as for it's interpretation, I think you need to say more about what this represents before we can offer meaningful opinions.

Comment: The scatterplot represents a bootstrap sample of size 100,000 for the vector of spatial (geometric) medians obtained from datapoints in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Comment: 3 D scatterplots (and other 3 D plots) are notoriously hard to interpret. You could look at a lattice of 2 D plots. You could also look at other graphs.